# php subscribers sql query too big?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In my app, you can subscribe to users to get their updates and such... but if you lets say subscribe to 2000 people the query is going to be way too big and i dont know if its going to work/crash or is the correct way to go...

This is the query that run with 15 subscriptions of a user and his self:

```
SELECT * FROM updates WHERE uid='433154988124' || uid='643474995854' ||
    uid='841341889862' || uid='231955782795' || uid='763438359221' ||
    uid='232345661645' || uid='786313664389' || uid='311617571586' ||
    uid='895988518181' || uid='576877484624' || uid='119448961897' ||
    uid='963671595174' || uid='342987961447' || uid='259688255351' ||
    uid='746656932975' || uid='716846928846' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0, 15
```

So what tells me that this will work with 1000+ and more subscriptions?

Is it the way to go or doing it another way is better?

Comment: This is not the correct way. Where are your subscriptions saved? You should think about a joined select.

Comment: their saved in another table called subscribers... so another way is to join them instead of fetching the IDs and adding them in the SQL query string..

Comment: Yes thats the way. Rick Hoving mentioned it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific example, the following should be assumed

1. The uid field is INT
2. You have an index specified as (uid,date) on updates (if uid is the PK, ignore this and just have a date index for ordering)

Bad query -

```
SELECT * FROM updates 
WHERE uid IN (
    433154988124,
    643474995854,
    841341889862,
    231955782795,
    763438359221,
    232345661645,
    786313664389,
    311617571586,
    895988518181,
    576877484624,
    119448961897,
    963671595174,
    342987961447,
    259688255351,
    746656932975,
    716846928846,
) ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0, 15
```

As mentioned by others though, a link table will be a more efficient way to go about it so that you can run this better query.

```
SELECT updates.* 
FROM updates 
INNER JOIN users_subscriptions
ON users_subscriptions.uid = updates.uid
ORDER BY updates.date DESC LIMIT 0, 15
```

Answer (score 5):

This is going to be very slow at a 1000+ subscriptions. What you want to do is create a link table UserSubscriptions or something like that. In that table you can store your user id and the id's it is subscribed to. Within your query you can just join those two tables.